How can I make a point-pattern-fill interlaced symbol in GeoServer SLD
I want to make a point-pattern-fill symbol which is interlaced styling in Geoserver, but seem like impossible.
Could you guys show me how to make this style?


You need two PolygonSymbolisers to offset the marks (and another to color the polygon). So to get an effect like this:

You need a Rule like this:
   <Rule>
      <Name>Offset Symbols</Name>
      <PolygonSymbolizer>
        <Fill>
          <CssParameter name="fill">#ff9300</CssParameter>
        </Fill>
      </PolygonSymbolizer>    
      <PolygonSymbolizer>
        <Fill>
          <GraphicFill>
            <Graphic>
              <ExternalGraphic>
                <OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="burg02.svg" />
                <Format>image/svg+xml</Format>
              </ExternalGraphic>
              <Size>
                <ogc:Literal>20</ogc:Literal>
              </Size>
            </Graphic>
          </GraphicFill>
        </Fill>
        <VendorOption name="graphic-margin">3 3 21 21</VendorOption>
      </PolygonSymbolizer>
      <PolygonSymbolizer>
        <Fill>
          <GraphicFill>
            <Graphic>
              <ExternalGraphic>
                <OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="burg02.svg" />
                <Format>image/svg+xml</Format>
              </ExternalGraphic>
              <Size>
                <ogc:Literal>20</ogc:Literal>
              </Size>
            </Graphic>
          </GraphicFill>
        </Fill>
        <VendorOption name="graphic-margin">21 21 3 3</VendorOption>
      </PolygonSymbolizer>

      <LineSymbolizer>
        <Stroke>
          <CssParameter name='stroke'>#000000</CssParameter>
        </Stroke>
      </LineSymbolizer>
    </Rule> 

The key lines are the <VendorOption name="graphic-margin"> which make the graphic "bigger" - so the 2nd image is offset from the first one, you will need to play around with the actual values to get the layout you require with your graphic.

Thanks. Using VendorOption 'graphic-margin' take effects，but it hard to take the appropriate parameters to Make the image's spacing neat

They're just pixels, as you know the size of your icon and the spacing you require it should be easy
